# Javascript Compare Index with Array Value

Tags: javascript

I have a main array, and an object that contains an array of items. I want to see if the object that contains items matches the main array index. If a match, then write to the console.

```
var mainItems = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,"car", "boat", "truck", "plane"];
var nonStandardItems =
{
    "items": [
        {

            "value": "8",
            "code": "8ic"
        },
        {
            "value": "boat",
            "code": "10bt"
        }
    ],

}

if( nonStandardItems.items.slice(-1)[0].value == mainItems.indexOf(nonStandardItems.items.slice(-1)[0].value)  ){
    console.log("you are right");
}
```

However, I only get a value of -1, and an error. What am I missing?

**EDIT**
I am pulling data from a different data sources, all containing junk data. However, the last item in the junk data array is the item I need.

I want to check if the results from my api request match an "expected" or "standard" set of data. For example, my nonStandardItems object is an example of what I get back from the api.

I want to parse it, and check to see if the LAST item in the items array has a value that matches the index of my standard items array. My junk items array contains numeric and text data, but the last item will always have either a numerical or textual code that I expect.

The example was contrived and rushed, so I apologize for the spelling, syntactical and explanation mistakes. The error the console threw was that nonstandardItems.items[-1].value did not exist.

Comment: I dont really get what your trying to do. Can you describe it better?

Comment: Sounds like you want `….value == indexOf(….code)`, not `.value` twice

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: It's `mainItems.indexOf` not `mainItemsindexOf`

Comment: when you use indexOf, this return -1 if value not exists in array, in your case you say if mainItem contains "14" this return -1 and is evident that is not ok.
Now, you can use mainItems.includes("14") and not indexOf this return true or false and is not necessary a comparison

Answer (score 0):

Use filter():

```
if (nonStandardItems.items.filter(v => mainItems.indexOf(v.code) == v.value).length > 0) {
    console.log("you are right")
}
```